# PDFBox. Generate multipage document with the same image

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox and java to generate a pdf document. The document has several pages with text and images. Every page has the same images in the header and footer. I am currently creating a new PDImageXObject and calling drawImage() with the new object every time I add a new page. The resulting document is very heavy and I suppose it is so because it contains repeated copies of the same image.

What would be the most effective way to do this?. Most probably, pdfbox has a much better way of managing document wide resources. I am new to pdfbox and frankly I could not find documentation or examples about this specific use case.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered the question yourself. You don't have to call `new PDImageXObject` every time, once per file is enough. However you'll have to call `drawImage`. (You could save slightly more space if the header and footer are 100% identical by using a form XObject, but you won't save very much, unless the hearder/footer is very complex).

Comment: Tilman, thanks for the answer. I made a test of your suggestion and it worked fine, reducing the file size to almost the size of one image. To do this test, I had to build a dictionary of `PDImageXObject` objects in order to keep track of which images are already loaded and which need to be created anew.

I wonder if the class `PDResource` and associates in pdfbox are intended for that purpose.

Many thanks again

Comment: PDResource is a resource dictionary; these exists for pages, patterns, forms and some more. It contains images, shadings, patterns, colorspaces, extended graphics states, etc. This is something for the PDF structure itself, not really for your optimization.